# Azure Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, networking, azure-private-link

For some use case, I rejected the approved private end point for a storage account. But I can’t move the state from Rejected to approved.

I tried using AzCLI and powershell to move from rejected state to approve state for the private end point but it’s not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created private endpoint with storage account and rejected like below:

[image]

> ***Note*** that: Azure Storage Accounts do not have a built-in feature to approve a rejected private endpoint within the Azure portal or management interfaces. During the creation of a private endpoint, you can approve, deny, after being refused, you cannot approve.

```c
$approve = @{
    Name = 'myPrivateEndpointConnection'
    ServiceName = 'myPrivateLinkService'
    ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
}
Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection @approve
```

```c
$deny = @{
    Name = 'myPrivateEndpointConnection'
    ServiceName = 'myPrivateLinkService'
    ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
}
Deny-AzPrivateEndpointConnection  @deny
```

When I check same in the portal, I can only remove the rejected private endpoint that was built in.

[image]

To remove rejection private endpoint via PowerShell you can make u of below command:

```c
$remove = @{
    Name = 'myPrivateEndpointConnection'
    ServiceName = 'myPrivateLinkService'
    ResourceGroupName = 'myResourceGroup'
}
Remove-AzPrivateEndpointConnection @remove
```

***Reference***:

[Manage Azure Private Endpoints - Azure Private Link | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/manage-private-endpoint?tabs=manage-private-link-powershell)